# Removing/excluding items from legend in an ArcFM Silverlight viewer

Tags: legend, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, arcfm, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I'm customizing an ArcFM Silverlight viewer (which is essentially an ArcGIS Silverlight viewer in a different package and with some additional tools). I managed to make a legend via the [Legend Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/Silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Legend.html) and [Sample: Legend with Templates](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#LegendWithTemplates).

[image: the legend in my viewer]

The last three layers (`InsetMapMarker`, `TextTemporary`, and `BufferLayer`) are things automatically generated by the ArcFM viewer tools. It will confuse to end users to see them ("what's a buffer layer, I'm not making any buffers"), and potentially mess with functionality if they turn them on or off. So I really ought to exclude them from the legend.

I was *very* happy to find this Q&A [How do I exclude raster layers from legend? (Silverlight, ArcGIS Server)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60020/how-do-i-exclude-raster-layers-from-legend-silverlight-arcgis-server/60026#60026) and adapted the code snippet to exclude the last three layers (see below). However, this has no effect -- they're still visible in the legend.

```
private void Legend_Refreshed(object sender, Legend.RefreshedEventArgs e)
{
    LayerItemViewModel removeLayerItemVM = null;

    if (e.LayerItem.LayerItems != null)
    {
        foreach (LayerItemViewModel layerItemVM in e.LayerItem.LayerItems)
        {
            if (layerItemVM.IsExpanded)
                layerItemVM.IsExpanded = false;
            if (layerItemVM.Label == "InsetMapMarker")
                removeLayerItemVM = layerItemVM;
            if (layerItemVM.Label == "TextTemporary")
                removeLayerItemVM = layerItemVM;
            if (layerItemVM.Label == "BufferLayer")
                removeLayerItemVM = layerItemVM;
        }

        if (removeLayerItemVM != null)
            e.LayerItem.LayerItems.Remove(removeLayerItemVM);
    }
    else
    {
        e.LayerItem.IsExpanded = false;
    }
}
```

I know very little about C# and the Silverlight API, and guessing isn't getting me very far. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this in a discussion on Esri's GeoNet: [Controlling Layers in Legend Control](https://geonet.esri.com/message/167372#167372). The method is to **include a `LayerIDs="[list]"` property in the legend declaration**.

> So for instance, you only want to display your baselayer in the
>   legend:
>
> ```
> <esri:Map>
> <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="baseLayer" Url="..." />
> </esri:Map>
> ```
>
> in legend:
>
> ```
> <esri:legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}" 
> LayerItemsMode="Tree" 
> LayerIDs="baseLayer" 
> ShowOnlyVisibleLayers="True" />
> ```
>
> To add layers to your legend, just separate them by a comma.

This worked in my case, since I have a limited set of layers and they are not going to change frequently (if ever). There are additional suggestions later in that discussion about removing all graphics layer, etc., however I didn't need a solution that advanced and so haven't tested it.